# How do GitFlow branches map to Test Environments

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-flow

Gitflow has Feature branches merging into Develop branch which then merges into Master branch.  In terms of having a Develop, Test, Pre-Prod and Prod environments, how do these 4 environments map to Feature branches, Develop branch and Master branch.

Often hear conflicting accounts of how they should map to each other (e.g. Develop branch is pushed to Test Env or not) so was after clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Having digged deeper into this, it seems GitFlow branches do not have to have a 1 to 1 relationship with Environments.  That said a relatively common mapping is as follows:

[image]